# Filter df -h to only show 'Mounted on' part

Tags: linux, bash

this is the normal output of df -h:

```
df -h
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s2s1  932Gi   14Gi  823Gi     2%  500637 4293577168    0%   /
devfs           193Ki  193Ki    0Bi   100%     673          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s5    932Gi  3.0Gi  823Gi     1%       3 8628536760    0%   /System/Volumes/VM
/dev/disk1s3    932Gi  367Mi  823Gi     1%    1816 8628536760    0%   /System/Volumes/Preboot
/dev/disk1s6    932Gi  4.0Mi  823Gi     1%      20 8628536760    0%   /System/Volumes/Update
/dev/disk1s1    932Gi   90Gi  823Gi    10%  789694 8628536760    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
map auto_home     0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
```

I need to filter it to have:

```
/
/dev
/System/Volumes/VM
/System/Volumes/Preboot
/System/Volumes/Update
/System/Volumes/Data
/System/Volumes/Data/home
```

So basically I need only the "mounted on" column of the command df -h.

Any idea?

Comment: `df -h | awk 'NR > 1 {print $NF}'` but using `gnu df` you can use: `df --output=target | tail -n +2`

Comment: `df --output=target | sed 1d`  or `df --output=target | awk 'NR>1'`

Comment: @anubhava df -h | awk 'NR > 1 {print $NF}' this done it! Thank you very much. Can you explain to me how it works?

Comment: `NR > 1` skips first header record and `print $NF` prints last file of each record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df --output=target
```

If you need mount targets, you can also look at `findmnt`. It has tons of formatting options, the list you want can be done with

```
$ findmnt --real -O TARGET
```

Comment: Hi, --output=target it's a recognized option for df.

Same goes for findmnt, for info I'm on a CentOS 6.10.